# Django views query output mixup when multiple users are using, how to prevent that

Tags: python, html, django

Hi am trying to select an option in html page and after running and doing some operations am trying to print those data
For single user it is working fine but when multiple users are running at almost same time
The data s getting mixed up and showing duplicate data and some time it is showing half data

Could any one tell me how to saparate each user session and prevent output mixup

am doing this code in python and django, selecting input from html and doing operations in django and printing those data in html again

Any leads would be very helpful, thanks

Comment: Forgot to mention, am doing this code in python and django, selecting input from html and doing operations in django and printing those data in html again

Comment: Hi there. If you want to add or change something in your question, edit The question. Commenting is harder to follow properly.